CMake and Doxygen for multiple targets
I've never used Doxygen (I know, I know, I used a now obsolete system for the longest time). I'm trying to add it to a CMake project in C that compiles various targets (libraries, executables...). My expectation is that it would generate documentation for each target, but instead I get a single html/ directory that contains almost nothing (it lists the header files, but not the c files and the only items it lists are a few structs). Yes, the code is liberally documented with /// comments.
Here's my heavily simplified CMakeList.txt:
enable_language(C)
project(AMIreadN2Data)

add_library(N2readData_static    STATIC N2readData.c SimpleLog/SimpleLog.c ListHash/ListHash.c)
target_link_libraries(N2readData_static    config)

add_executable(N2dateStrToNano N2readData.c SimpleLog/SimpleLog.c ListHash/ListHash.c)
add_executable(N2nanoToDateStr N2readData.c SimpleLog/SimpleLog.c ListHash/ListHash.c)
target_compile_definitions(N2dateStrToNano    PUBLIC -DSTANDALONE_N2_DATESTR2NANO)
target_compile_definitions(N2nanoToDateStr    PUBLIC -DSTANDALONE_N2_NANO2DATESTR)
target_link_libraries(N2dateStrToNano    m config)
target_link_libraries(N2nanoToDateStr    m config)


find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
#   set(DOXYGEN_USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE ../README.md)
    doxygen_add_docs(N2DataReadDoc ALL)
#   add_custom_target(doc ALL)
endif()

So, how do I setup my cmake config so that I get a documentation for each target ? Or is that the wrong way to go ?

Function doxygen_add_docs accepts list of files and directories for which it is needed to generate the documentation. Looks like you forgot to specify that list.

Which version of doxygen are you using? As a first step I would try to generated the documentation outside of CMake, use a default settings file (doxygen -g to generate it) and probably set RECURSIVE=YES and EXTRACT_ALL=YES (probabbly best to set all EXTRACT_... to YES and read-up in the manual for some hints and meaning of the settings.

Does doxygen_add_docs(N2DataReadDoc ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ALL make any difference? Possibly also experiment with setting WORKING_DIRECTORY depending on where your source files are located.

Version of 1.9.8. Adding ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} gives the same result of having a single and very incomplete documentation with no C files and only a few structs indexed. How to you get a specific doxygen compilation for each CMake target ?
